# Why doesn't this regex reject trailing slashes (using negative lookahead)?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm using the following regex (PCRE) to (very basically) validate an URL to start with *http[s]://* and reject trailing slashes: `^https?://.+(?!/)$`

However, the negative lookahead does not prevent the regex from matching an url with a trailing slash.

I know that I can simply use `^https?://.*[^/]$` but I'd like to know why the lookahead does not work.

Comment: Like Jens says: If you’re already at the end of the string, there is no `/` after it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your lookahead checks if the last character of the string (the one before the end-of-line) is followed by a slash. It is not, since no character follows it, so the `(?!/)` will never prevent a match.

You could use

```
^https?://.*(?!/).$
```

or

```
^https?://.+(?<!/)$
```

Comment: Thanks - I chose the latter solution as this one looks much cleaner.